# iFrame fails to load in iOS Safari until reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iframe

I have a simple iframe which is used to display a vimeo video on my site, as so:

```
<div class="video">
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/88893424" width="960px" height="540px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And it works like a charm on all standard computer browsers.  Ajax is used throughout the site, and transitioning between pages that have videos and don't work exactly as you would expect - Ajax grabs the new page content, slides it on, deletes the old content, and the video works perfectly.

However, on iOS Safari, the video does NOT load.   The space for the video is reserved - the other content on the page flows around the area where the video should be, which tells me the div is loading, and the height and width information of the iframe element is being registered by the browser.  But no video, nothing.  Reload the new page, though, and the video is there and plays just fine.

So my question is: Why is the reload required?  What could I be doing wrong that is causing the AJAX to fail?  I have read several answers across SO that seem to incriminate header information and cross-site drama, but it is danced around and not explained.  Can anyone give me a clear understanding of what's going on here?

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior on Mac Safari 7.0.6 as well